# LSCopyDefaultHandlerForURLScheme alternatives to check if current application is the default browser?

Tags: swift, macos

What is the proper way to check if my application is set as the default browser since LSCopyDefaultHandlerForURLScheme is deprecated on 10.15?

I get a bundle ID reference when I do:

```swift
let bundleID = LSCopyDefaultHandlerForURLScheme("http" as CFString)?.takeRetainedValue() { ... }
```

And then I could just compare `bundleID` with `Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier`.

If I use *LSCopyDefaultApplicationURLForURL* instead, I get an URL. In order to compare my application bundle ID against LSCopyDefaultApplicationURLForURL, I would need to access the bundle of the URL which my application might not have access to due to sandboxing.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can compare the `lastPathComponent` of the `URL` with the name of your app.

Example, considering you app's name is `MyApp`

```
var isDefaultBrowser: Bool {
    LSCopyDefaultApplicationURLForURL(URL(string: "http://")! as CFURL, .all, nil)
        .map { $0.takeRetainedValue() as URL }
        .map(\.lastPathComponent)
        .map { $0 == "MyApp.app" }
        ?? false
}
```

Comment: Is there anyway to create a variable like this on iOS? @vauxhall

Answer (score 0):

You can check the bundle identifier against the returned URL from `LSCopyDefaultApplicationURLForURL` with

```
func isDefaultBrowser(for bundleIdentifier : String) -> Bool {
    guard let defaultbrowserURL = LSCopyDefaultApplicationURLForURL(URL(string: "http://")! as CFURL, .all, nil)?.takeRetainedValue() as URL?,
        let bundle = Bundle(url: defaultbrowserURL) else { return false }
    return bundle.bundleIdentifier == bundleIdentifier
    
}
```

Comment: How would you do this for iOS? @vadian

Comment: @Ryan Frankly I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
guard
    let defaultHandlerURL = LSCopyDefaultApplicationURLForURL(URL(string: "https://")! as CFURL, .all, nil)?.takeRetainedValue() as? URL,
    let defaultHandlerURLBundleId = Bundle(url: defaultHandlerURL)?.bundleIdentifier
else { return }
```

Comment: LSCopyDefaultApplicationURLForURL is deprecated. How do you do this without LSCopyDefaultApplicationURLForURL.